# TO GATHER INCOMING NFS SESSIONS

Tags: powershell

I want to gather incoming NFS Sessions. We then interpret this information and filter out any duplicates. If a duplicate is found, an occurrence value is upped.
I wanted to keep a log of one unique record per connection, updated with the most recent connection datetime

How can I do that ?

Script :

```
[array]$ResultArray = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\IncomingNFSConnections.csv

$ServerConnections = Get-NfsMountedClient
foreach ($Connection in $ServerConnections) {
$Date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
$ServerObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
  ClientComputerName = $Connection.ClientIpAddress
  Date               = $Date
  Occurence          = 1
  }
  $ResultArray += $ServerObject
}
```

My desired output:

```
"ClientIpAddress","Date","Occurence"
"10.123.12.12","2022-08-02","7"
"10.123.12.14","2022-08-02","10"
```

the output of Get-NfsMountedClient

```
ClientId     ClientIpAddress TotalSessions
--------     --------------- -------------
141733920814 10.123.12.12    1            
141733920825 10.123.12.13    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your desired output, I believe this is what you want to do:

```
$result = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Scripts\IncomingNFSConnections.csv' | 
Group-Object ClientIPAddress | 
Select-Object @{Name = 'ClientIPAddress'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
              @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'}},
              @{Name = 'Occurrence'; Expression = {($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property TotalSessions -Sum).Sum}}


# show on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to new csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Scripts\NFSConnections.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

As per your comment, I think what you want to do is to first append new data to the existing IncomingNFSConnections.csv file and then create a summary of that, correct?

If that is the case here, you can do:

```
# first we append the data from the current connections to the already existing csv file
$Date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
Get-NfsMountedClient | 
Select-Object ClientIPAddress,
              @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {$Date}},
              @{Name = 'Occurrence'; Expression = {1}} |
Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Scripts\IncomingNFSConnections.csv' -Append -NoTypeInformation

# next, create a summary of that file where we sum the Occurrences per IP address
$summary = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Scripts\IncomingNFSConnections.csv' | 
Group-Object ClientIPAddress | 
Select-Object @{Name = 'ClientIPAddress'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
              @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {$Date}},
              @{Name = 'Occurrence'; Expression = {$_.Group.Count}}
              # or use @{Name = 'Occurrence'; Expression = {($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Occurrence -Sum).Sum}}

# show on screen
$summary | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to new csv file
$summary | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Scripts\NFSConnections.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thanks but I can't see `Get-NfsMountedClient` cmd-let.

Comment: @Arbelac I have edited my answer. Is that what you need?

Comment: btw I have similar issue too.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73237740/gathering-smb-open-files-via-powershell  could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check ,if this is new connection or old connection and keep it in a loop

```
$mainobject = @()

foreach($connection in $connections ){
        
$IpExists = $mainobject | where {$_.remoteaddress -eq $connection.RemoteAddress }
if ($IpExists){

## update count
$IpExists.countt = $($IpExists.countt)+1

}
else {

##  we got new ip address
$mainobject += [PSCustomObject]@{
Remoteaddress = $connection.RemoteAddress
countt =1

}

}
```

your  `get-nfsmountedclient` and foreach should be in a never ending a  loop with a sleep timer